# Empty response body with 200 status code for ajax post call only on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, axios

Thank you in advance. Googled for this issue. Couldn't find a valid solution. I am writing a webapp using vue.js as front end and using AWS lambda functions with api gateway as REST service
As part of webapp, i have a login component which makes ajax call to AWS endpoint. I am using axios.post for ajax call.

Here is code snippet:

```
loginUser(username, password) {
        const vm = this;

        var apiUrl = `${this.host}/user/login`;
        const requestBody = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
        };
        axios
            .post(apiUrl, requestBody, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'} })
            .then((response) => {
                window.console.log('Login Response')
                window.console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                store.dispatch('login', { user: response.data, error: '' });
                vm.resultSubject.next(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                vm.resultSubject.error('Failed Login');
                window.console.log(error);
            });
        return this.resultSubject;
    }
```

Everything works fine when i login using laptop browser but when trying the same on my mobile browser is giving me empty response. the status code is 200 but no response data. Making a GET call works fine. Attaching some snapshots showcasing the issue

[network tab iphone safari - empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV8i3.png)

[console tab iphone safari - response logged with actual js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L78Oa.png)

[network tab laptop safari - with response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQkFl.png)

[console tab laptop safari - response logged with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4tpA.png)

[network tab iphone safari - with response on different GET call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gk40.png)

Comment: on the iphone, the data is logged on line 28 of `speed-test-service.js` ... on the laptop, it's line 1 of `app.xxxxxxx.js` - so ... you're comparing apples with oranges

Comment: Thank you for quick response. It's an interesting observation. I updated snapshot showcasing original file is same in both browsers. I believe remote web inspector is showcasing non-minified reference of js file

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the main problem is in server code.

Weird behavior in mobile is due to username being camel-cased by mobile browser. In desktop browser when i type username it is abc_xyz but in mobile it is Abc_xyz which ends up server not finding user in DB.
Server code is poorly written to not handle case in-sensitivity of username and no proper handling of error conditions.
Lesson learned, take a close look at request body.